# ListView não aparece no emulador

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no Android Studio e tentando usar uma ListView, porém quando executo o projeto, a lista não aparece no emulador!

**CODIGO XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.tma.carteiravirtual.carteira.tela_inicio"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_tela_inicio">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_MeuSaldo"
        android:id="@+id/btnSaldo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/lbl_SaldoAtual"
        android:id="@+id/lblSaldoAtual"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSaldo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#3ea92d" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Saldo atual"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblSaldoAtual"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblSaldoAtual"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lblSaldoAtual" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Saldo total:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblSaldoAtual"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/lbl_SaldoTotal"
        android:id="@+id/lblSaldoTotal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:textColor="#3ea92d" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="R$"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Total gasto:"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="R$"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/lbl_TotalGasto"
        android:id="@+id/lblTotalGasto"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:textColor="#a60b0b" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Meus gastos:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listGastos"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bMais"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bMais"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bMais" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/bMais"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/bMenos"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bMais"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bMais"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bMais" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: .XML]
[image: QUANDO EU EXECUTO O EMULADOR]
Espero ajuda!

Obrigado

Comment: Seria bom vc colocar o código Java também, mais especificamente a parte que popula a lista

Comment: Precisa necessariamente preencher a lista para que ela apareça?

Comment: Sim, é necessário que preencha, você pode preenche la com um array criado na mão por vc mesmo, somente pra faze-la funcionar

Comment: a lista está vazia, então ela não aparecerá. esses ""item 1 subiten 1" é apenas um demonstrativo da aparência na hora que voce constrói o xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um TextView  para ser exibido quando a lista está vazia.

1- No arquivo de layout da lista

```
    ...
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
    ...
    />
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/listEmpy"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="( Lista vazia )"
    />
    ...
```

2- No onCreate da activity

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.listEmpty));

    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que a `ListView` apareça quando você executar o projeto, esta deve ser "carregada" com os itens que irão ser exibidos. Caso a lista esteja vazia, não irá mostrar na tela do device.

[Exemplo](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65) de implementação de uma `ListView`